# How to connect to tor via Stacksoft.net's socks 5?

Tags: c#, socks, tor

I'm trying to fetch a page via tor using socks 5 protocol with [Stacksoft.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/starksoftproxyc/) library:

```
ProxyClientFactory cf = new ProxyClientFactory();
var p = cf.CreateProxyClient(ProxyType.Socks5, "127.0.0.1", 9051, "", "");
var c = p.CreateConnection("www.google.com",80);
```

When I run this, I'm getting following exception:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
Inner exception:An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

The exception is thrown when the program tries to read the response from google.com `stream.Read(response, 0, response.Length);` :

```
    private void SendCommand(byte command, string destinationHost, int destinationPort)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte addressType = GetDestAddressType(destinationHost);
        byte[] destAddr = GetDestAddressBytes(addressType, destinationHost);
        byte[] destPort = GetDestPortBytes(destinationPort);

        //  The connection request is made up of 6 bytes plus the
        //  length of the variable address byte array
        //
        //  +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
        //  |VER | CMD |  RSV  | ATYP | DST.ADDR | DST.PORT |
        //  +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
        //  | 1  |  1  | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
        //  +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
        //
        // * VER protocol version: X'05'
        // * CMD
        //   * CONNECT X'01'
        //   * BIND X'02'
        //   * UDP ASSOCIATE X'03'
        // * RSV RESERVED
        // * ATYP address itemType of following address
        //   * IP V4 address: X'01'
        //   * DOMAINNAME: X'03'
        //   * IP V6 address: X'04'
        // * DST.ADDR desired destination address
        // * DST.PORT desired destination port in network octet order            

        byte[] request = new byte[4 + destAddr.Length + 2];
        request[0] = SOCKS5_VERSION_NUMBER;
        request[1] = command;
        request[2] = SOCKS5_RESERVED;
        request[3] = addressType;
        destAddr.CopyTo(request, 4);
        destPort.CopyTo(request, 4 + destAddr.Length);

        // send connect request.
        stream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);

        //  PROXY SERVER RESPONSE
        //  +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
        //  |VER | REP |  RSV  | ATYP | BND.ADDR | BND.PORT |
        //  +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
        //  | 1  |  1  | X'00' |  1   | Variable |    2     |
        //  +----+-----+-------+------+----------+----------+
        //
        // * VER protocol version: X'05'
        // * REP Reply field:
        //   * X'00' succeeded
        //   * X'01' general SOCKS server failure
        //   * X'02' connection not allowed by ruleset
        //   * X'03' Network unreachable
        //   * X'04' Host unreachable
        //   * X'05' Connection refused
        //   * X'06' TTL expired
        //   * X'07' Command not supported
        //   * X'08' Address itemType not supported
        //   * X'09' to X'FF' unassigned
        //* RSV RESERVED
        //* ATYP address itemType of following address

        byte[] response = new byte[255];

        // read proxy server response
        stream.Read(response, 0, response.Length);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i am currently working with the exact same socks5 library and Tor, will keep referring to this post and post my findings as i get a working solution; i think the source of your issue is not your code but Tor, it uses socks4a by default to accept connections so if you want to use socks5 you need to indicate that in the config file so Tor runs a socks5 accepting socket (i think, will verify) :)

Comment: sounds good! let me know what you find

Comment: Looks like they assume that the read call will grab 255 bytes, this is a silly assumption and likely why it breaks..

Comment: @paulm read will read any number of bytes in response between 1 and 255

Comment: Yeah so the assumption in the code is wrong, likely why high latency breaks it? "ProxySocket" seems to be a better lib

Answer (score 2):

sorry for the delayed response, i have worked out this small "library" which essentially exposes a singleton Tor class and a socks class; this is part of a larger project and i did not want to delay my answer. i hope my approach provides you with some direction.

i just want to note that the only issue i have experiences while testing is that i don't seem to get the complete http return payload, meaning the proxy class seems to capture only a portion of the html code from the web server. i believe this is due to the large latency involved with the Tor network. i tried increasing the size of the buffer array but that did not help. if you come up with a solution i would be very grateful

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Starksoft.Net.Proxy;

using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

using System.Threading;

namespace networking
{
    namespace client
    {

        internal class proxy
        {
            public struct conn
            {
                internal TcpClient http;
                internal IProxyClient Proxy;
                public ProxyType proxy_type;

                public string proxy_host;
                public int proxy_port;
                public string target_host;
                public int target_port;
                public string recv_packet;

                public void proxy_config(string target_host, int target_port, string proxy_host, int proxy_port, ProxyType type)
                {
                    this.target_host = target_host; this.target_port = target_port;
                    this.proxy_host = proxy_host; this.proxy_port = proxy_port;
                    this.proxy_type = type;
                }
            }
            public conn proxy_conn;
            internal proxy(string target_host, int target_port, string proxy_host, int proxy_port, ProxyType type)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket allocated.");
                this.proxy_conn = new proxy.conn();
                this.proxy_conn.proxy_config(target_host, target_port, proxy_host, proxy_port, type);
                ProxyClientFactory factory = new ProxyClientFactory();
                this.proxy_conn.Proxy = factory.CreateProxyClient(type, proxy_host, proxy_port);
                this.proxy_conn.Proxy.CreateConnectionAsyncCompleted += new EventHandler<CreateConnectionAsyncCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_connected);

                //this.Proxy.CreateConnectionAsync(obj.target_host, obj.target_port);
            }
            internal void connect()
            {
                this.proxy_conn.Proxy.CreateConnectionAsync(this.proxy_conn.target_host, this.proxy_conn.target_port);
            }
            private void proxy_connected(object sender, CreateConnectionAsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection Error!");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message);
                    return;
                }
                else if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    // get a reference to the open proxy connection
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Tor!");
                    this.proxy_conn.http = e.ProxyConnection;
                    Console.WriteLine("Proxy referenced.");
                }
            }
            public void send(string data)
            {
                this.proxy_conn.http.Client.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
            }
            public string recv()
            {
                byte[] rcvBuffer = new byte[1024]; //1024
                int bytes = this.proxy_conn.http.Client.Receive(rcvBuffer, 1024, SocketFlags.None);
                this.proxy_conn.recv_packet += ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBuffer, 0, bytes);
                return this.proxy_conn.recv_packet;
            }

        }

        internal class Tor
        {
            private static Tor instance;

            private Process tor;
            //private conn obj_conn;
            private Tor(){}
            internal static Tor Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Tor();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
            internal void tor_start()
            {
                if (this.tor == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tor init...");
                    this.tor = new Process();
                    this.tor.StartInfo.FileName = "tor.exe";
                    this.tor.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                    Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                    this.tor.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                    this.tor.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    this.tor.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    this.tor.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    this.tor.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    this.tor.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, args) => { stdout__tor(sender, args); });
                    this.tor.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, args) => { stderr__tor(sender, args); });

                    this.tor.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("Strapping input...");
                    this.tor.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    this.tor.BeginErrorReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A Tor process already exists.");
                }

            }
            internal void tor_stop()
            {
                this.tor.StandardOutput.Close();
                this.tor.StandardInput.Close();
                this.tor.StandardError.Close();
                this.tor.Kill();
                this.tor.Dispose();
                this.tor = null;
            }
            internal void tor_restart()
            {
                tor_stop();
                tor_start();
            }
            private void stdout__tor(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs pipe)
            {
                if (pipe.Data.Contains("Bootstrapped 100%: Done."))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tor has been initialized.");
                    //this.obj_conn.Proxy.CreateConnectionAsync(obj_conn.target_host, obj_conn.target_port);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(pipe.Data);
            }
            private void stderr__tor(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs pipe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[ERROR]: " + pipe.Data);
            }
        }


    }


    public class socket
    {
        internal static client.Tor Tor_obj;
        internal static List<client.proxy> proxy_socks;

        public socket()
        {
            if (Tor_obj == null || proxy_socks == null)
            {
                if (Tor_obj == null)
                {
                    Tor_obj = client.Tor.Instance;
                    Tor_obj.tor_start();
                }
                if (proxy_socks == null)
                {
                    proxy_socks = new List<client.proxy>();
                }
            }
        }
        public int add(string type, string host, int port)
        {
            int index = -1;
            if (type == "proxy")
            {
                proxy_socks.Add(new client.proxy(host, port, "127.0.0.1", 9050, ProxyType.Socks4a));
                index = proxy_socks.Count() - 1;
                proxy_socks[index].connect();
                return index;
            }
            return index;

            }
    }
}

namespace myprog
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            networking.socket connections = new networking.socket();
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            int conn_index = connections.add("proxy", "checkmyip.com", 80);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            networking.socket.proxy_socks[conn_index].send("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: checkmyip.com\r\n\r\n");
            Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(networking.socket.proxy_socks[conn_index].recv()));
            Thread.Sleep(50000);
        }
    }
}
```

i invoke thread.sleep() to ensure that the Tor process has fully connected, then the proxy connection to Tor is established, and at that point the request is made.